# How to prevent ASP .Net app which uses async from deadlocks?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, async-await

Consider an ASP .Net MVC app which was written using async. It happens that async was used on top layers and bottom layers with some gaps (e.g. .Result calls) which lead to deadlocks.

I heard that `.ConfigureAwait(false)` might help but I'm not sure how. So the question is: how to use `.ConfigureAwait(false)` to prevent deadlocks?

This very app has a class separating presentation layer from business logic. I thought of making all business logic methods return Task with `.ConfigureAwait(false)`. Would that be correct/suffice?

Comment: Without any code, I can only assume you wrote in the wrong way. Without knowing fully what is the ASP.NET thread model, and what is async/await, you'd better stick to the synchronous model.

Comment: See http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html

Comment: `I thought of making all business logic methods return Task` there is no good reason to do this.  Otherwise you are adding extre layers and complexity for absolutely no reason.

Answer (score 2):

Using `ConfigureAwait(false)` is rather a workaround than the ultimate solution. You might eliminate the deadlock caused by `task.Result`, but you'd still be blocking the request thread, effectively killing the primary advantage of using `async/await` on the server side, which is improved web app scalability.

The other not-so-obvious issue would be that the continuation code after `await task.ConfigureAwait(false)` would loose access to the HTTP request's ambient information provided by `AspNetSynchronizationContext` (e.g. no more `HttpContext.Current.Items`).

Ideally, you should refactor your service/data layer to work with tasks, and use `async/await` "all the way down" to the root method, which is an asynchronous controller method. It's not that difficult, just use `Task<T>` instead of `T` for your data access interfaces:

```
public interface IAsyncData
{
    Task<int> AsyncData { get; }
}
```

instead of

```
public interface IData
{
    int Data { get; }
}
```

Then use async `Task-based` data access APIs in when implementing your data repository, and use `await data.AsyncData` wherever you'd use `data.Data` when implementing your MVC controller.

You can do such conversion gradually, by using `Task.FromResult` for `AsyncData` with your existing synchronous data access layer.